# Black screen after upgrading from Ubuntu 21.04 to 22.04

Tags: boot, upgrade

After I upgrade the system an error message appeared saying that the upgrade finished with some errors.
After that, I tried to open a terminal but I couldn't. When I clicked the button to open it, it looked like it was loading, but after a few seconds the loading symbol disappeared and it didn't open the terminal.

So I decided to reboot the system, but when I did it, a black screen appear and I wasn't able to do anything. I tried pressing Ctrl+Alt+F3 and nothing happened.

I also tried to start the system from Recovery mode (I think that's the name for it) from the grub menu, since I have a dual boot (Windows 10 and Ubuntu), but again, a black screen appear and I wasn't able to do anything.

Could anyone help me please?

These are my system specs:
Motherboard: Gygabyte A320-S2H
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3500X
GPU: Radeon RX 580
RAM: 16GB

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 had one QA-tested & supported upgrade path, which was to the next release being Ubuntu 21.10.  You've gone outside that QA-tested & *supported* procedure, thus a re-install maybe your best option.  In future I'd suggest using the QA-tested & supported *release-upgrade* paths.

Comment: FYI:  I'm involved with QA-testing, and keep systems with all *supported* releases; when I didn't need my 21.04 desktop system, as I didn't need a 21.10 system - i used it to QA-test install the then *jammy* desktop system; ie. used a re-install to upgrade it to a release I didn't then have on my non-primary boxes.  That is the upgrade path I'd have suggested, if you're asking about a desktop system.  For more help though, providing the error messages you mention, would have been helpful as well as how you performed the *unsupported* upgrade (even if you just followed EOLUpgrades doc)

Comment: "some errors" is not very helpful.

Comment: Try connecting to a another display

Comment: "*the upgrade finished with some errors*" may be very bad news. It means you had non-Ubuntu or wrong-version packages on your system that conflict with your upgraded system. The ultimate cause is almost always something the human installed. There are several answers here already that can teach you how to identify and remove those packages. If you don't want to spend an afternoon learning that skill, then the fast method of repair is to backup your data and reinstall.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. How could I do a fresh reinstall? Is it from the grub menu? How could I do it over the old Ubuntu such that it doesn't interfere with the windows partition? Sorry if these are dumb questions, but I new at this kind of stuff.